# Trying to use COUNT(*) with a SELECT Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know the query should only return on value because only one of the customers is verified as a student.

Can someone please help me with structuring the select statement with `COUNT(*)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WHERE` to filer only students and then count them`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS StudentCount
FROM Customer 
WHERE Student = 1
```

or use `COUNT` combined with `CASE` (may be slower):

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Student = 1 THEN 1 END) AS StudentCount
FROM Customer
```

or even `MySQL`:

```
SELECT SUM(Student = 1) AS StudentCount
FROM Customer
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and it's closer to what I want for sure. However, the count is coming back as "12," when the count should just be "1," since only one customer is verified as a student. I'm not entirely sure why it's doing that. My only guess is that it's the 12th value in the data? 

Is there anyway to remedy that?

Comment: @StephanieWong Do you have the same record 12 times (the same name and last name)? Your data contains 12 records with flag Student = 1

Comment: Whoops lol. I was trying to be helpful. 

But you're right, that was a huge assumption on my part. thank you so much for your help. I was able to find the 12 records